# Change options of already used latex package with doxygen

Tags: cmake, latex, doxygen, pdflatex

I'm using *cmake* with *doxygen* to generate documentation based on some markdown files. There are some special characters in those markdown files that I can't control (add by users and I just run my script). I found a solution by using the option `utf8x` instead of just `utf8` with the `inputenc` package and use `ucs` package as well.

So, I added the following line into `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(DOXYGEN_EXTRA_PACKAGES ucs "[utf8x]{inputenc}")
```

Which lead to having the following lines in `refman.tex` file:

```
% Packages requested by user
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

The problem is, there is already `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the file which lead to an error on generating the pdf file using `make pdf`.

I can solve that by have a special bash/python script that replaces `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with whatever I want, but it seems strange to me that there is no way to make doxygen replaces/removes aready used packages as there is already `EXTRA_PACKAGES` which can be used to add extra packages.

Comment: A quote from the hyperref documentation: "Note: utf8 is now the default in LATEX and ucs is no longer recommended." Don't use the `utf8x` option and don't use the `ucs` package. This will only lead to problems!

Comment: If you are having problems with special characters, I'd rather use an unicode aware engine like lualatex or xelatex to compile the document.

Comment: It seems that one can use LATEX_CMD_NAME to change the engine in doxygen https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9000

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Please show a small minimal working example that shows the problem consisting of the markdown code as well as the doxygen settings used (i.e. doxygen -x Doxyfile). Without this information it is not possible to say anything sensible.

Comment: Seems there is no way in doxygen to change already used packages based on the used template [latexrefman.tpl](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/templates/latex/latexrefman.tpl).

Comment: @albert My doxygen version is "1.8.13", but I'm generating everything through cmake.

Comment: CMake is not relevan for this question. The doxyge version 1.8.13 is quite old (December 29, 2016) so I defenitly advise you to update to the current doxygen version 1.9.4.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have tried to set `DOXYGEN_LATEX_CMD_NAME` in cmake but the generated `Makefile` is still using "pdflatex". Seems to be an issue with cmake [FindDoxygen](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindDoxygen.html).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I managed to set xelatex as the engine. I should set `DOXYGEN_USE_PDFLATEX` with `NO` explicitly. I still have a problem with xelatex but that is another issue. Thanks a lot for help.